# W0640: Cell variable month_ defined in loop (cell-var-from-loop) - pylint

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pylint

I have some code like this but I got error from pylint and I don't know what's wrong with it and what should I do

```py
tuples = ((1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8))
for tuple_ in tuples:
    df[df["date"].apply(lambda d:(d.month==tup[1]) & (d.year==tup[0]))].count()[0]
```

df is a pandas dataframe and "date" column is pandas datetime
code works well but there is error message from pylint


**Update**:
I just created small function that could remove pylint error but I want to know if my approach is a right one!

```py
tuples = ((1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8))
def _group_date(df_, tup_):
    return df[df["date"].apply(lambda d:(d.month==tup[1]) & (d.year==tup[0]))].count()[0]

dict_ = {}
for tuple_ in tuples:
    dict_[f"{tuple_ }"] = _group_date(df, tuple_ )
```